# PowerShell scheduled job not running at startup

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

I am trying to create a job that runs at startup on Windows Server 2012 R2 Core. The job runs a script that connects to a network shares and then mounts a VHD located on that share.

The script itself works and when registering with the `-RunNow` parameter the job is fired and runs as expected. Running the job with the `Start-Job` Cmdlet also works fine.

However, the job does not fire at startup like specified in its trigger.

What I did to create the job:

```
$Trigger = New-JobTrigger -AtStartup  
$JobOptions = New-ScheduledJobOption -RunElevated -RequireNetwork  
Register-ScheduledJob -FilePath C:\Scripts\Test.ps1 -Name Test -Trigger $Trigger -ScheduledJobOption $JobOptions -RunNow
```

I can clearly see the results of it working after doing this. But when restarting the server the results aren't there, but the job says it was last run not long after the reboot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the New-JobTrigger cmdlet to create a startup trigger it's a good idea to specify a random delay period of 30 seconds or more to avoid conflicts at startup. This will also help ensure a greater chance of success for the job.

```
$trigger = New-JobTrigger -AtStartup -RandomDelay 00:00:30
```

You also want to check the status of your job once you've restarted and logged back in with the `Get-Job` cmdlet.

Comment: After playing with the delay a bit, I've found that a delay of about 1 minute was most consistent. Thanks!

Comment: As well as doing this it could be helpful to test for any needed services be started before running commands in your script.

Comment: I'm trying to do this in AWS and I've added a RandomDelay of up to 00:01:30 and my script still doesn't run.  No error, no nothing.  If I run it manually after the machine is up and I RDP into it the script runs fine.  Maybe something with AWS is preventing the job from running.

Comment: I had to go 00:02:00 to make anything run on an Azure server :(